# Why can I cast a reaction spell on the same turn as an action spell, but not on the same turn as a bonus-action spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, actions, reactions

Jeremy Crawford mentions the following example in [this Sage Advice column](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/sage-advice/ability-check) (reiterated in the [Sage Advice Compendium](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf)):

> Cornelius the wizard is casting *fireball* on his turn, and his foe casts *counterspell* on him. Cornelius has *counterspell* prepared, so he uses his reaction to cast it and breaks his foe’s *counterspell* before it can stop *fireball*.

This is an example of 2 third-level spells being cast on the same turn. I don’t understand why this is negated by the rules if Cornelius was a sorcerer and used Quickened Spell to cast *fireball* as a bonus action instead, because the rules say that if you cast a spell as a bonus action you could only cast a cantrip during the same turn. Yet it would be allowed without quickened spell applied to *fireball*.

I don’t understand why you can cast a normal *fireball* (1 action casting time) and still be able to use a reaction to counter a *counterspell*, yet you can’t do the same if you actually cast *fireball* as a bonus action which is supposed to be even faster - made more confusing for me if you add the fact that you must sacrifice 2 sorcery points to do it as a bonus action as a sorcerer, yet you are allowed to counter if you take longer and without sacrifice of sorcery points.

**Why can I cast a reaction spell on the same turn as an action spell, but not on the same turn as a bonus-action spell? What is the relevant rule?**

Comment: It's not clear what exactly your question is here... But it seems to be a duplicate of one of these two questions (or at least closely related): [Casting multiple spells in a single round](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49532/casting-multiple-spells-in-a-single-round), and [Can you cast 2 spells at the same time?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/126051/can-you-cast-2-spells-at-the-same-time)

Comment: The questions are indeed similar, but not the same and I cannot find an answer for my question under those questions. The first question you refer me to is maximum number of spells per round, not per turn as mine is, the second refers to simultaneity and the rules for reactions state clearly that only the attack of opportunity actually interrupts the triggering condition, so counterspell happens after the casting of say, fireball, and the second counterspell after the first, its sequential not simultaneous. I ask: why this works if cast as an action but not if it is cast as a bonus action?

Comment: So are you asking what exactly the relevant rule is (about bonus-action spells)? Or are you already aware of the relevant rule, and asking *why* the rule says what it says?

Comment: You reference the rules for bonus action spellcasting already in your answer, is there something specific about them that is confusing to you? Are you asking why this rule exists?

Comment: @V2Blast I think I know which is the relevant rule that should be applied, after all it is written clearly, I guess I just don’t get why, in a case like this, it ends up restricting sorcerers spending sorcery points but not wizards.

Comment: @Piero: In that case, [you'd be specifically asking about the designer intent behind a certain rule, which is no longer allowed here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7964/questions-about-designer-reasons-are-off-topic)... We can tell you what the rule is, but explaining why the designers chose to word it in the way they did isn't really something we can do.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose I am confused actually by the rules regarding spellcasting times, I don’t understand why you can cast a normal fireball (1 action casting time) and still be able to use a reaction to counter a counterspell, yet you can’t do the same if you actually cast fireball as a bonus action which is supposed to be even faster, more confusing for me if you add the fact that you must sacrifice 2 sorcery points to do it as a bonus action as a sorcerer, yet you are allowed to counter if you take longer and without sacrifice of sorcery points.

Comment: @V2Blast ok I get that makes sense, so what is the rule here?

Comment: @Piero: If it's alright with you, I can edit the question to focus on asking for the rule instead.

Comment: @V2Blast sure please go ahead, I’m sorry I don’t really know the rules around here, I just want to improve my dming no trolling intended!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is asking about designer reasons.

Answer (score 7):

## The restriction only applies to bonus-action spells

The relevant rule regarding [bonus-action spells](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/spellcasting#BonusAction) appears in the rules on spellcasting in the basic rules or PHB (p. 202):

> A spell cast with a bonus action is especially swift. You must use a bonus action on your turn to cast the spell, provided that you haven't already taken a bonus action this turn. **You can't cast another spell during the same turn, except for a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action.**

There are no other restrictions on casting multiple spells in the same turn. If you cast a spell as your action, it doesn't restrict your ability to cast a reaction spell. (It can, however, prevent you from casting any spell as a bonus action; the rule is agnostic of order, so if you cast any non-cantrip spell as an action, then you can't cast a spell as a bonus action.)

---

As you point out, the sorcerer does have the Quickened Spell [metamagic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/sorcerer#Metamagic) option:

> When you cast a spell that has a casting time of 1 action, you can spend 2 sorcery points to change the casting time to 1 bonus action for this casting.

This gives the sorcerer versatility, freeing up their action to spend their action doing other things for the cost of 2 sorcery points. However, it does not ignore the bonus-action spell rule; like all other characters, if the sorcerer casts a bonus-action spell (even if it's a Quickened spell that normally has a casting time of 1 action), the only other spell they can cast on their turn is a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action.

Although a sorcerer can't cast a quickened *fireball* and another leveled spell on the same turn, Quickened Spell can still be quite useful; it frees up their action to Disengage (e.g. if they want to move away from an enemy from being attacked), Dodge (e.g. if they want to minimize the chance of being hit by an attack or take a lot of damage from an enemy *fireball*), attack with a weapon, drink a healing potion, or anything else they can do as an action.

---

In fact, you could cast up to 3 leveled spells during your turn, but only if you have [the fighter's Action Surge feature](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/fighter#ActionSurge):

> Starting at 2nd level, you can push yourself beyond your normal limits for a moment. On your turn, you can take one additional action on top of your regular action and a possible bonus action.
>
> Once you use this feature, you must finish a short or long rest before you can use it again. Starting at 17th level, you can use it twice before a rest, but only once on the same turn.

(You could get the feature through multiclassing between fighter and any caster class, or using the Eldritch Knight fighter subclass.)

You could cast a leveled spell as your action, then use Action Surge to get another action on the same turn, and use that second action to cast another leveled spell. Finally, if the relevant trigger occurs, you could cast a reaction spell (e.g. you would get hit by an opportunity attack so you cast [*shield*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shield), or you get damaged by the attack so you cast [*hellish rebuke*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hellish-rebuke), or an enemy tries to [*counterspell*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/counterspell) your action spell so you cast *counterspell* on it).

---

In short, the rules may seem a little weird/arbitrary, but they're only interested in whether or not you've cast a bonus-action spell:

- If you have cast a bonus-action spell, the only other spell you can
  cast that turn is a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action (no
  reaction spells on that same turn).
- If you haven't cast a bonus-action spell, then you are free to cast a
  reaction spell on your turn.

Comment: they do, in this case at least, seem a little weird/arbitrary as you say and as I suspected (and feared) as in RAW, so Cornelius's fireball + counterspell is fine but quickened fireball + counterspell is not, or magic stone + fireball + counterspell etc. I really would love to hear the RAI on this, thanks a lot you guys are great!

Comment: It would be good if the answer specifically mentioned the interaction with Quickened Spell.

Comment: @Marq: Good point, will do.

Comment: That is a lot of words to utterly fail to address OP's question of "why is reaction + action allowed but reaction + bonus disallowed", I'm afraid.

Comment: @vonBoomslang: Well, OP's actual question is a [designer-reasons question, which is off-topic](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7964/questions-about-designer-reasons-are-off-topic), so all we can answer with is the relevant rule.